# Kernel of linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

On the Hilbert Space $L^2([0,\infty))$, define the linear operator $\Lambda$ by
$$(\Lambda f)(x)=2f(x+1),~~~~~~x\ge0.$$

Describe the Ker$(\Lambda)$ and Ker$(\Lambda ^*)$.

My attempt:
Let $2f(x+1)=0 ~~for~~ x\ge0$

Then I have Ker$(\Lambda)$=$\{f\in L^2([0,\infty)):f(x)=0~, x\in[1,\infty)\}$.

But I found the solution is Ker$(\Lambda)$=$\{f\in L^2([0,\infty)):f(x)=0~~a.e. x\in[0,1]\}$

Why? How to compute the Kernel?

Comment: Maybe you should try writing out a justification for why you think the kernel is $\{f\in L^2([0,\infty)):f(x)=0~~\text{a.e.} ~ x\in[0,1]\}$ here. For example, $f(x) = 1_{(1,2)}$ is zero on $[0,1]$ but isn't mapped to $0$ by $\Lambda$.